# How to temporarily override a DNS setting for a certain domain name to point to localhost?

Tags: localhost, hosts

I need ubuntu to use a certain domain name to point to a localhost address temporarily. How could I confgure for that ?

Answer (score 2):

What are we talking about here? A single host, a network, a dns server serving your domain?

I'm gonna go with single host:

```
echo '127.0.0.1 somehost.example.org' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

If you are in fact in a network then please add more information to your question.

Comment: thanks I tried modifying the /etc/hosts file but it didn't had any effects even after restart..

Comment: You may also need to ensure that the "hosts: " line in "/etc/nsswitch.conf" lists "files" before "dns". For example: `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] wins dns mdns4`

Answer (score 0):

I developed a Node.js command line utility called [hostnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hostnames) to do this effortlessly and programmatically.

Install `hostnames` using `npm install hostnames`.

Then, add a hostname using `sudo hostnames add` (for example, point `lickstats.com` to `localhost` using label `lickstats`.

Finally, enable the override using `hostnames enable lickstats -t` (`-t` enables the override temporarily until you hit <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>).